# Register And Login To SMF With CURL

Tags: php, curl, smf

I'm working on a website that has a forum area, I will probably use the SMF forum software for the forum. Users can register and log in on the website. I would like to achieve that when they register on the website, they get also registered on the forum (they don't have to register twice). And also when they log in to the website that would also log them into the forum so they don't have to log in twice.

I think this should be possible with curl but I need to see some example code so I can figure it out. The main problem is that on the registration page there is a captcha so I don't know how to get over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a post on the SMF forums that explains how to post a topic with cURL.
http://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=53433.0

You could use the same method for registration, just using different form variables

Addendum:

> The main problem is that on the
>   registration page there is a captcha
>   so I don't know how to get over that.

I think the point is that you're not supposed to bypass the captcha.

Answer (score 1):

The basic steps to this are simple.

First, the Registration. When you register on the main site, simply add a Database entry to the Forum's database with the correct user information:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE (`Field1`, `Field2`) VALUES(`Value1`, `Value2`)
```

The next part is a bit trickier.

If you feel comfortable editing the source of the forum, you simply have to find where they check the login cookies, and add in a check for your cookie aswell. (Given they are on the same domain.)

```
if(checkSiteCookie() == true) { // ... do stuff ...
```

turns into

```
if(checkSiteCookie() == true || checkCompanyCookie() == true)) { // .. do stuff..
```

If the Site and the Forum are on the same domain, you could use the forum's cookie function to set the cookie in your script.

```
setMyCookie();
setForumCookie();
```

If you can't, you could always try using AJAX to submit their login form first to your login page, then the forums. After both of them have been completed, redirect them to the proper page.

```
// Get your Site Cookies and Log In
$.post("mylogin.php", form, function(data){

    // Get the Forum's Cookies
    $.post("forumlogin.php", form, function(data){

         // Reload the Page
         window.location.reload(true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Exactly my thoughts, it's probably more efficient than using cURL. Although, if the site shares the same user base, make your site USE SMF's user database table than making two user bases. Keep in mind that you need to know what they use to encrypt the password so you need to look at SMF's login function for this.

Comment: I voted this answer down because simply inserting into the database is seldom the right answer, in anything other than a simple data entry form.

First of all, you need to guarantee that all the data is safe, secondly you need to understand that the data entered via a form can be sent to multiple tables, each with foreign indexes to the main table, and finally not all the data is stored in the tables as it is entered in the form.

Like I said, inserting directly into the database is seldom the right choice.

(Senior Software Engineer 20+ years)