# Use CAKEPHP session to autologin a member into SMF

Tags: php, cakephp, smf-forum

I have website built in CakePHP and am using SMF forum. When a user gets registered on the website, a record is inserted into the smf_members table and this user is able to login to the forum. This part works well.

I want the user to auto login to forum when user login into the website. I have searched on google and did not find anything useful.

How do I make user auto login to SMF?
Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: set the session when user logs into website,put if condition if session is set autologin to forum..!!

Comment: @SiddeshBhalke thanks for the comment. I need to know how do we autologin into SMF.

Comment: check this link "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2014232/register-and-login-to-smf-with-curl"

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to register a user before logging in. This registration will be in the `{db_prefix}_members` table.
2. after you can call login api with this Ajax url: "http://your-domainname.com/index.php?action=login2"
3. this `login2()` method will call in `Source/LogInOut.php` file and login user will redirect to SMF forum page.

and most importent:

comment `// checkSession('post');` this function. if you are using smf `2.0.14` version.